# Date/Time field outputting time with additional minutes

Tags: entries, datetime

I've having an issue where a Date/Time field (time only) is outputting the time in the front-end template with an extra 10 minutes.

In my template I'm using `entry.startTime|date("g:ma”)`.

In the DB the `field_startTime` for the entry is `2016-10-15 16:00:00`, but on the front-end I’m seeing 4:10pm.

Could anyone tell me where are these extra 10 minutes coming from, please?

This is happening both locally and on the dev server, using Craft CMS 2.6.2949

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You are using the wrong variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

The `10` is there because it means `October` not `10 minutes`.

You have to use `| date("g:ia”)`.